# twitter Rate limit exceeded google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter

I am using google app engine and would like to download tweets from a given user.

I am simply calling http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/USERNAME.json

But almost always (About 99% of times) I get "Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour" does this problem has something to do with Google App Engine Cloud inrastructure ? What shall I do? (for example storing data on other server and then call from there...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does this problem has something to do
>   with Google App Engine Cloud
>   inrastructure

Yes.

The API method you're calling is [rate-limited](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting):

> The default rate limit for calls to
>   the REST API is 150 requests per hour.
>   The REST API does account- and
>   IP-based rate limiting. Authenticated
>   API calls are charged to the
>   authenticating user's limit while
>   unauthenticated API calls are deducted
>   from the calling IP address'
>   allotment.

This works fine if your app has a dedicated IP; on App Engine, many applications will potentially use the same source IP for their urlfetch request, so unauthenticated requests to the Twitter API will all draw from the same quota.

I haven't tested this, but my understanding is that even for calls that don't require authentication, if you choose to authenticate your request it will be counted against your account quota instead of the shared IP quota.

Nick Johnson posted [a tutorial](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Writing-a-twitter-service-on-App-Engine) on how to send authenticated API calls to Twitter from App Engine.

Comment: You're correct - for this API, you can authenticate and it'll ratelimit based on your credentials. The only exception to this is the search or streaming APIs, which don't support authentication at all.

Comment: I had problems to sign up my app, (Twitter error page appeared every single time I tried to register). So fetching the user page (twitter.com/USERNAME) and "parsing" the page worked very fine. How ever you answer looks very good, so I think is correct to mark it as valid.