# DownloadError: ApplicationError: 5 in urlfetching twitter RSS on AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rss, twitter

I'm playing with twitter statuses rss feed on Google AppEngine (in python). I perform a urlfetch and I systematically get a

DownloadError: ApplicationError: 5

when I deploy the app whereas everything is fine when I test it locally on my dev server.

I guess it's a timeout issue due to AppEngine limitations. I already extended urlfetch deadline to 10sec.

How can I work around this issue ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284205/twitter-rate-limit-exceeded-google-app-engine/3285127

Comment: Thanx... I didn't think about it !! I'll try with authenticated requests.